# How will Allah forgive me after shouting at my father?

Tags: allah, sin, tawba, parents, forgiveness

My parents fight so much. My father screams at my mother and sometimes hit her (lightly) but it affects me and everyone in the house because we get scared.

One day my father was super angry and blamed my mother about something (they were fighting about the same thing for a very long time), he was about to hit her until I got very mad and started to scream and shout at my father "Stop this! Don't hit her! Why do you always do this to my mother! Imagine if I was married and my husband hit me!!! Would you be ok with that?!" I said many things to him in anger and all he did was say "calm down. please just calm down."

When the fighting and shouting stopped, I went to my room and started crying so much because I love my parents soooooo much and I knew that I ruined everything with my father by shouting at him. After crying, I went to my father and apologized and hugged him and told him i would never shout at him again. He forgave me.

The good thing that came out of this is that my father calmed down and never hit my mother again. He also became a more relaxed person.

This incident happened approximately more than one year ago. Since that time I have been feeling very depressed because I know in islam if someone raises their voice or disrespects their parents they will never see paradise and it is a major sin. I have prayed to allah to ask for forgiveness for disrespecting my father but I still feel like any prayer or any good deed that I do is a waste.

I just want to feel or know that I have been forgiven from Allah. I really don't know what to do. I feel extremely terrible and heartbroken every time i pray. I don't want to feel this way. I really regret that I screamed at my father.

What do I do? How can I be forgiven by Allah? Or will I never be forgiven? I am lost. Please help me.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mercy of Allah (SWT) is infinite. He said in the holy Quran "O My servants who have transgressed against their souls! Do not despair of the Mercy of God: for God forgives all sins: for He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful." Quran 39:53 and we see many times Telling us that he is the most forgiving and most merciful. Allah (SWT) said in the Quran "My Mercy Encompasses All Things" Quran 7:156. Allah is so gentle with people and loving. He loves when we repent to him and ask his forgiveness. Ask his forgiveness and talk to him and he will always listen and love him and know that he is most gentle and most loving and most forgiving and most merciful. Allah forbade us from despairing in his mercy and scholars say that it's a major sin to despair in the mercy of Allah. Know that whatever sin it is will never NEVER be greater than the mercy of Allah (SWT). Always remind yourself that Allah is EXTREMLY EXTREMLY and Infinite in his mercy. Keep asking for his forgiveness. There's a Hadith that the Prophet of Allah (SAW) said: that Allah the Almighty said: O Son of Adam, so long as you call upon Me and ask of Me, I shall forgive you for what you have done, and I shall not mind, O sin of Adam, were your sins to reach the clouds of the sky and were you then to ask forgiveness of Me, I would forgive you." Related by Al-Tirmidhi. Keep asking Allah to forgive you sincerely and keep doing good deeds and be gentle and kind with your parents and stay calm and love your parents.

may Allah forgive us all.
and 
Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as this is an inter-personal sin, it is unlikely that Allah will hold you accountable for it after the fact that your father has forgiven you and after you have repented.

Remember that Allah loves you more than your father does, and he is more forgiving that your father is.